# Wijmo charts - passing in dates from PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, type-conversion, wijmo

I'm using Wijmo, a jQuery library that includes a few chart plugins. When working with dates, data is specified using the following format:

```
seriesList: [{
    label: "Q1",
    legendEntry: true,
        data: {
            x: [new Date(1978, 0, 1), new Date(1980, 0, 1), new Date(1981, 0, 1), new Date(1982, 0, 1), new Date(1983, 0, 1)], 
            y: [12, 21, 9, 29, 30]
        },
    offset: 0
}]
```

Notice the `x` axis of the `data` object, all of the items are instances of `Date`.

When passing this data down in a JSON object from PHP the dates aren't in a format that Wijmo can handle, so I pass a string down and instantiate `Date` with that string.

However, now I'm working with more complex charts I want to get away from having to loop through the data in JavaScript to change the date string to a `Date` object.

So here's my question: is it possible to pass a date down from PHP to JavaScript, in a format that JavaScript (read: Wijmo) will understand without the need to convert? If not, can anyone think of an alternative solution that might solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ben, I am not familiar with returning JSON from PHP, but in other APIs I have seen actual Date objects passed to the client in JSON format like so:

```
{ "CreatedAt":"\/Date(1317591213230)\/" }
```

This should be turned into a date object when you parse it in JSON. Remember, JSON is a JavaScript Object so this is just returning a Date function that will get executed.